# packets sniffer from client-server(udp) connection python 2.7 (only)

Tags: python-2.7, udp, packet-sniffers

I wrote client which sending packets to a server and now I need  create an adversary which listens (on localhost) to the connection between the client and the server, and prints the packet contents, the adversary is not a part of the connection. I am having some problems with that I know I need to use raw socket but I don't know why i can't do this.

server:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server_address = ('localhost', 12321)
print >> sys.stderr, 'starting up on localhost port 12321'
sock.bind(server_address)

while True:
    data, address = sock.recvfrom(100)
    if data:
        sent = sock.sendto(data, address)
        print >> sys.stderr, 'sent %s bytes back to %s' % (sent, address)
```

client:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server_address = ('localhost', 12321)
i = 0

    while True:
        f = open("poem.txt", "r")
        for line in f:
            time.sleep(3)
            i += 1
            sent = sock.sendto(line, server_address)
            data, server = sock.recvfrom(100)
        f.close()

    print >>sys.stderr, 'closing socket'
    sock.close()
```

adversary:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
s.bind(("localhost", 1))
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)
s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)
while True:
   print s.recvfrom(12321)
```

in the adversary I get all kind of messages but not those the client send (the client sent a song). please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is with your binding,
socket.bind() accept an address tuple (IP,PORT)

your client is bonded to port 12321 but your adversary is set to port 1

```
s.bind(("localhost", 1)) #change 1 to 12321
```

also, socket.recvfrom() gets a buffer size as an argument and not the port.

```
   print s.recvfrom(12321) #change to buffer size
```

take a look at the documentation for sockets: 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html

also, may I suggest using Scapy tool,
it's easy to use on both Windows and Linux

just type `pip install scapy` in your cmd and
on windows make sure you install npcap among scapy
https://nmap.org/npcap/windows-10.html 
and you're ready to go

after installing scapy then you would just need a line like this:

```
sniff(filter="udp and host 127.0.0.1 and dst port 12321", prn=lambda x:x.sprintf("{IP:%IP.src% -> %IP.dst%\n}{Raw:%Raw.load%\n}"))
```